# Primary key is incremented for all entities

Tags: java, jpa

I'm writing simple SE application with CRUD operations on two entities. I've noticed that primary key is auto-incremented for both entities. When I persist new object of `FirstEntity` it gets ID = 1 which is fine but, then I persist `SecondEntity` and it's ID is 2 but should be one because there is no other entities of type `SecondEntity`. What can be the reason of such occurence?

First entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries( value = {
@NamedQuery( name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e")
})
public class Employee extends AbstractModel<Long, Employee>{

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
private Long id;

@Basic
@Column( name = "FIRST_NAME" )
private String firstName;
@Basic
@Column( name = "LAST_NAME" )
private String lastName;
@Basic
@Column( name = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER" )
private String accountNumber;
@Column( name = "BIRTH_DATE" )
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birthDate;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinTable( name = "EMP_TASK", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn( name = "EMP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn( name = "TASK_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Second entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries( value = {
@NamedQuery( name = "Task.findFinished", query = "SELECT t FROM Task t where t.endDate <= :date"),
@NamedQuery( name = "Task.findActive", query = "SELECT t FROM Task t where t.startDate <= :date and :date <= t.endDate"),
@NamedQuery( name = "Task.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Task t")
})
public class Task extends AbstractModel<Long, Task>{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Basic
private String name;
@Column( name = "START_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;
@Column( name = "END_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date endDate;

@ManyToMany( mappedBy = "tasks", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE )
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Abstract model:

```
public abstract class AbstractModel<ID extends Serializable, T extends AbstractModel<ID, T>> implements Serializable {

private Class<T> modelClass;

abstract public ID getId();

/**
 * Default construcot initializing class field.
 */
public AbstractModel(){
    modelClass = resolveModelClass();
}

/**
 * Default {2code equals(Object obj)| function for all entities
 * @param obj
 *      object to be compared
 * @return 
 *      true if object are eqaul, false otherwise
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(!modelClass.isInstance(obj))
        return false;

    T other = modelClass.cast(obj);
    if ((this.getId() == null && other.getId() != null) || (this.getId() != null && !this.getId().equals(other.getId()))) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    return (getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0);
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return modelClass.getName() + "[ id=" + getId() + " ]";
}

private Class<T> resolveModelClass(){
    return (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}
```

}

Persisting method:

```
private static void addNewEmployee() {
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    // setting fields of emp

    EmployeeDAO empDAO = new EmployeeDAOImpl();
    emp = empDAO.create(emp);
    if (emp != null) {
        System.out.println("New employee with ID: " + emp.getId() + " has been saved");
    } else {
        System.out.println("A problem occured while trying to persist employee entity");
    }
}
```

where `EmployeeDAO.create(Employee)` uses `EntityManager` to persist object

Comment: Can you provide some source code?

Comment: provide `hbm.xml` or `annotated class`

Comment: Sorry for troubling you. I've had a blackout and I had been thinking that GenerationType.AUTO will work as GenerationType.IDENTITY. However, I'm using Apache Derby provided with NetBeans and it looks like AUTO works as TABLE. Moreover, IDENTITY does not work with Derby, because `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` is thrown

Comment: Clearly Apache Derby *does* provide "generated always as identity" and the JPA provider should be perfectly capable of providing that when the user puts IDENTITY in there. Maybe your JPA provider has a limitation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY` on the id-Columns. (using autoincrement of the table).

`strategy = GenerationType.AUTO` will make hibernate (or whatever JPA implementation you are using) picking a number from its OWN Auto-increment collection that is shared accross all available tables.

See here for all options: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html

Update due to comment:

You could try to use `GenerationType.Sequence`

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="sequence1", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="sequence1")
private long id;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Apache Derby does not provide `GenerationType.IDENTITY` and we have to work on it, because of classes purpose

Comment: @Nav You could try to use `GenerationType.Sequence`. See update of my post.

Comment: Bless You. It's been very helpful and Apache Derby accepts it ;)